# Scroll a scroll View Manually in program with gesturesDetector?

Tags: android, scroll, gesture

I have 2 scrollable views above and below like 2 blocks. Both have to be scrolled. Now I want to scroll both of them with the same gesture on scrolling and not individually.I am not using Toolbars or Collapsable Toolbar.
I have created a Parent Relative Layout class and have overriden to get all the ScrollEvents with Gesture Detector. But I don't know how to scroll the views.

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
```

Now from here I don't know how to scroll a particular scroll view smoothly. I know default implementation does it but I am not using the default implementations.
I can use

```
scrollView.scrollTo();
```

but what values to pass and how to do it smoothly I don't know. 
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScrollView` has a method `smoothScrollTo(int x, int y)` its like `scrollTo(int, int)`, but scroll smoothly instead of immediately.

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY){
     scrollview.smoothScrollTo(distanceX, distanceY);
}
```

Comment: Yes but it would create a jank still. It like every time the user touches we intercept the scrolling like movement. If I use this smoothScroll the speed it starts with will create a problem as it would look unnatural

Comment: You can try to use a Scroller, its an Object that helps you control the speed of control and some extra parameters